# Multiplying 2 lists in Lisp

Tags: function, lisp, multiplication

I have a function that takes 2 lists as input and I would like to make it so that everything in the first list, is multiplied with everything in the second list, and then the sum is calculated.

Here's my function so far:

```
(defun multiply(a b)
(if (eq a nil)
0
(progn
      (* (car a) (car b))
  (multiply (car a) (cdr b)))
))
```

Currently all I'm trying to get it to do is take the first number from the first list, and multiply one by with everything in the second list. However I get this error from when the function is re-called within the function:

(This is what I inputted, '(1 2 3) and '(4 5 6))

The value 1 is not of type list.

(MULTIPLY  1  '(5 6))

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify if the expected result is 32 or 90 in your example?

Comment: Sorry, should be 32..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is `loop` acceptable?

**Case 1**

If the result should be *90* as in

```
(+ (* 1 4) (* 1 5) (* 1 6) (* 2 4) (* 2 5) (* 2 6) (* 3 4) (* 3 5) (* 3 6))
```

then you could do

```
(defun multiply (a b)
  (loop for i in a
    sum (loop for j in b
          sum (* i j))))
```

**Case 2**

If the result is supposed to be *32* as in

```
(+ (* 1 4) (* 2 5) (* 3 6))
```

then it would be

```
(defun multiply (a b)
  (loop 
    for i in a
    for j in b
    sum (* i j)))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to multiply two lists per element, you should just be able to use mapcar:

```
(mapcar #'* '(3 4 5) '(4 5 6))
```

As to the error in your existing function, this line should be:

```
...
  (multiply (cdr a) (cdr b)))
...
```

Comment: In emacs lisp one would require `cl` first: `(let () (require 'cl) (reduce '+ (cl-mapcar #'* '(3 4 5) '(4 5 6))))`.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe sounds like the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

```
(defun dot (l1 l2)
  (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'* l1 l2)))
```

The above solution is nice because it is purely functional, but, alas, it creates an unnecessary intermediate list. Of course, a [Sufficiently Smart Compiler](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler) should be able to eliminate that, but, practically speaking, you are better off using `loop`:

```
(defun dot (l1 l2)
  (loop for x in l1 and y in l2 sum (* x y)))
```

Note also that using [`list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm)s to represent [mathematical vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is not a very good idea, use [`vector`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_vector.htm)s instead.

Comment: Also note that you can still use `loop` with vectors, but use `across` instead of `in` then.

Comment: @Svante: that was left as an exercise for the reader (together with modifying the 1st version to work with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify `multiply` as

```lisp
(defun multiply(a b)
  (if (eq a nil)
      0
    (+
      (* (car a) (car b))
      (multiply (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
```

When you call

```
(multiply '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

it will return the sum

```
32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (*2Ls L1 L2)
    (apply map * (list L1 L2)))
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.